# Noise texture+bump node disables smooth shading

Tags: materials, node-editor

I did a hair for a model using curves, It looks smooth in the preview but in the render its not smooth. 
[image: print]

I know that what is creating this is the node setup that I'm using to give the hair effect, that is basically a streched noise texture connected to a bump node.

file:http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51177
[image: node setup]

Comment: maybe share your file?